# Use of L'hopital's rule

Tags: limits

Define $f:\mathbb{N}  \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(n)=\frac{sin (\frac{n\pi}{4})}{n}.$

May I know if we can use L'hopital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{n \to 0} f(n)$ ? If not, how can we evaluate the limit without the use of series?

Thank you.

Comment: The only sequences in $\mathbb{N}$ that converge to $0$ are the eventually constant ones. So $\lim_{n\to 0} f(n)$ exists if and only if $f(0)$ is defined (beforehand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as $\lim_{n\to 0}f(n)$ if $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: for *continuous* variable $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ , we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac{x\pi}4}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac\pi4\frac{\sin\frac{x\pi}4}{\frac{x\pi}4}=\frac\pi4$$

Since the above limit exists in the above case, it also exists and equals the above for *any* sequence $\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ instead of $\;x\;$ ...